# Editing an array from an imported file

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv

So I am dealing with a problem where I am importing text from a notepad into java and am trying to put it into a csv file. I have successfully managed to do so, but now I need to remove info from each line of the array in the csv.

So to help visualize its something like this:

```
Name = Bob, Age = 42, FavColor = Blue
Name = Clarice, Age = 20, FavColor = Red
Name = John, Age = 34, FavColor = Green
```

And I want to remove the Name =, Age = and FavColor = from each part of the csv so that I only have the relevant data. Would look like this:

```
Bob, 42, Blue
Clarice, 20, Red
John, 34, Green
```

For further understanding of what I am doing my code thus far looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{              
    String file_name = "C:/Users/etc....";      
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {           
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name); 
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile(); 

        sb.append("Name");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("Age");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("FavColor");
        sb.append('\n');

        int i;          
        for(i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
            sb.append(aryLines[i]);
            sb.append("\n");                
        }

        pw.write(sb.toString());
        pw.close();             
        System.out.println("CSV Written");          
    }       
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );           
    }       
}
```

The array is properly going through each line of the notepad info but I just am stumped on how to get the info removed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code suggests that the output looks different...

Comment: What is a `ReadFile` object and what library is it from?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the ReadFile object is from another class and is used to open the file and then go through line by line and convert to strings and then put those strings into an array in the code shown above. Then that array is written to a CSV Excel doc. The output may look funny cause the "file_name"/"file" is the notepad with my info there. So once it is put into the array it is then put into a CSV Excel doc where each info before the comma is put in its own cell of the Excel doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT**

Changed the regular expression to include word patterns with spaces:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

public class YourClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Path to the file being converted
        String infile = "C:/Users/.../test.txt"; // Some absolute path
        // Path to the destination output file
        String outfile = "C:/Users/.../test.csv"; // Some absolute path

        try {           

            // Read all rows from the infile
            List<String> rows = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(infile), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            // List of new rows to write to the outfile
            ArrayList<String> nrows = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Enumerate rows
            for (String row : rows) {
                // Remove any word followed by any number of spaces and
                // an equals sign followed by any number of spaces
                String nrow = row.replaceAll("[\\w\\s]+\\s*=\\s*", "");
                // Append edited row to new rows
                nrows.add(nrow);
            }               

            // Get file descriptor
            Path file = Paths.get(outfile);
            // Write rows to outfile
            Files.write(file, nrows, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            // Update G/TUI
            System.out.println("CSV Written");

        }       
        catch (IOException e) {
            // You should catch specific exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();           
        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: This worked best. Managed to properly convert it and to put everything its proper cells. Have to edit it a bit to change what got removed (got rid of the equal sign but not the info before it but shouldn't be too hard to change) but works perfectly!

Comment: @latiasfan What did the output look like? Can you show it here?

Comment: It shows up in a csv in the proper manner, but the issue is that for the instances where the cell has only "name = ajsldfkj" etc. they now only have the cell value. But I have some where its not simply one word so its like "Favorite Color = blue" And in those cases it removed "Color =" but not "Favorite" So it reads like "Favorite blue" in the cell instead of just  "blue"

Answer (score 0):

Since this is straight-forward, I will give you an overview:

1. Split by `,`, you will an array of 3 strings
2. Foreach element, split by `=`, you will get an array of 2 strings. Take the second string
3. Use `trim()` effectively
4. Check for array length at every step
5. You should look at things like how big is your file, since you are effectively appending everything to the `StringBuilder` object, which can run out of memory. Alternately, you could write to another file at every line, but the throughput will decrease. You can also think of batching them together to a file.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, I will try this and see how it works. I had tried looking up how to do this but I was banging my head against a wall as all the examples I could find weren't for cases of removing things in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace it with a regex:

```
replaceAll("\\w+ = ", "")
```

Comment: Ok I will look into this as well to see how it works.